# Adding two columns with blank entries as well getting all blank in final column

Tags: r, null, na, nonblank

I am trying to add multiple columns ( in R) with many ( not all) blank entries but in final column I am getting all blanks.
I am using simple +/- opertorfor this operation.

```
Final8$Abs_diff <- abs((Final8$prev_so_Qty + Final8$prev_dc_Qty + Final8$Import_Qty + 
                        Final8$Fs_trns_in_Qty) - 
                       (Final8$Trade_Qty + Final8$Fs_trns_out_Qty + Final8$crt_so_Qty + 
                        Final8$crt_dc_Qty))
```

I am felling that blanks entries are creating issue here, could someone help me how to avoid this situation

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE` to handle the missing values after `cbind` the columns.

```
Final8$Abs_diff <- abs(rowSums(cbind(Final8$prev_so_Qty, Final8$prev_dc_Qty,  Final8$Import_Qty,  
                        Final8$Fs_trns_in_Qty), na.rm = TRUE) - 
                       rowSums(cbind(Final8$Trade_Qty, Final8$Fs_trns_out_Qty, Final8$crt_so_Qty,  
                        Final8$crt_dc_Qty), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Great. Click the tick next to the answer in that case.

Comment: I thoght that might be the case :)  Have a look at the help section of SO sometimes.